# Make image bigger in a pop-up window in python tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Hy, can someone explain me why this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from PIL import Image , ImageTk
def full_dimensions (imag_fs):
    s = Tk()
    img = Label(s, image = imag_fs)
    img.pack()
    s.mainloop()

def mainz ():
    r = Tk ()
    _url = 'https://i.imgur.com/4m7AHVu.gif'
    _img = requests.get(_url)
    if _img.status_code ==200:
        _content = BytesIO(_img.content)
    else:
        _content = 'error.gif'
    _x = Image.open(_content)
    imag_fs = ImageTk.PhotoImage(_x)
    _x.thumbnail((100,100),Image.ANTIALIAS)
    imag = ImageTk.PhotoImage(_x)
    img = Button(r, image = imag, command = lambda:full_dimensions(imag_fs))
    img.grid(column=3,row=1)
    r.mainloop()

mainz()
```

returns me this output when i click on the button

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\test_image\prova.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    img = Button(r, image = imag, command = lambda:full_dimensions(imag_fs))
  File "E:\test_image\prova.py", line 7, in full_dimensions
    img = Label(s, image = imag_fs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
```

I want to make a windows pop-up when click on the button with the image at real dimension or however bigger.
So the first problem is that I want to understand why this code doesn't work.
Then if someone can suggest a module that can show a windows with the image and a navigation tool, like y and x scroll-bars and zoom-in and zoom-out buttons, that would be awesome, if not I will try to build a function by my self.
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the image.

You also should only use one root `tk.Tk()`, and one `mainloop`; you can display a new window popup with `tk.Toplevel`.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from io import BytesIO
import requests
from PIL import Image , ImageTk


def full_dimensions(imag_fs):
    top = tk.Toplevel(root)
    img = tk.Label(top, image=imag_fs)
    img.pack()


def get_image():
    _url = 'https://i.imgur.com/4m7AHVu.gif'
    _img = requests.get(_url)
    if _img.status_code == 200:
        _content = BytesIO(_img.content)
    else:
        _content = 'error.gif'
    print('image loaded')
    return _content


root = tk.Tk()

_content =  get_image()   
_x = Image.open(_content)
imag_fs = ImageTk.PhotoImage(_x)
_x.thumbnail((100, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)

imag = ImageTk.PhotoImage(_x)
img = tk.Button(root, image=imag, command=lambda: full_dimensions(imag_fs))
img.grid(column=3, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```